# Correspondence between the set of all normal subgroups of a group and the set of all congruences on that group.

Tags: group-theory

> Question: Prove that there exists a one one correspondence between the set of all normal subgroups of a group and the set of all congruences on that group.

I don't understand what does the term "set of all congruences on that group" means. Please tell me what do I suppose to show.

Comment: Do you know what a congruence on a group is?

Comment: No. Is it a quotient group?

Comment: It is not. You need to look up the definition in whatever material you got the problem from.

Comment: Note: "there is a bijection between sets $Y,Z$" just means that $Y,Z$ have the same cardinal, it's often not very interesting. The point here is that there's a natural such bijection. I included the definition of congruence in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A congruence on a magma $X$ (often, a semigroup) is a equivalence relation given by fibers of a homomorphism to another magma. Equivalently, it's an equivalence relation $\sim$ on $X$ such that ($x\sim x'$ and $y\sim y'$) implies $xy\sim x'y'$. The quotient of a magma by a congruence is a quotient magma; the quotient magma inherits the identities of the original magma; in particular for a semigroup (i.e., an associative magma), the quotient magma is associative as well.

If $G$ is a group, there is a **natural** bijection between the set of congruences and the set of normal subgroups, given by $\sim\mapsto M_\sim$, defined as $N_\sim=\{g\in G:g\sim 1\}$, and whose inverse bijection is given by $N\mapsto R_N$ defined as $R_N=\{(x,y)\in G^2:x^{-1}y\in N\}$.